# UIAlertController not in hierarchy in different entrance point

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uialertcontroller

I have an app that people can use to request service. I have a tab bar controller that uses a navigation controller on the 1st tab that had several pages for different stuff like service, location, and customer information. All have UIAlertViews, and everything works great when I put the tabBarController as the apps entry point. Then I decided to add a a different UIViewController that they could select the tabBarController or a different tabBarController. kinda 2 apps in one if that makes sense. When I put that UIViewController as the app entry point, all the UIAlertViews work except for the last one. It says "Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!." Here is my code

```
@IBAction func send(_ sender: Any)
{

    name.resignFirstResponder()
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    year.resignFirstResponder()
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    make.resignFirstResponder()
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    model.resignFirstResponder()
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    color.resignFirstResponder()
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    note.resignFirstResponder()
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "You will now email your service request. The recipient email adress and message will be preset, all you have to do is hit send.", message: "Message and data rates may apply.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default)
    {
        UIAlertAction in
        let mailcomposedViewController = self.configureMailController()
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()
        {
            self.present(mailcomposedViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            self.showMailError()
        }
    }

    alertController.addAction(okAction)


    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction of why the Alert work on one entry point, and not the other?

[image]

[image]

When I put the app entry point on the tab bar controller (top picture) everything works great. But when I put the entry point as the UIView (bottom picture) only the last part does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
    let yourCurrentVisibleViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController

    yourCurrentVisibleViewController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Or make your controller as subcontroller of **yourCurrentVisibleViewController** above. Maybe you try to call a method before your controller was not appear.

Comment: That worked for the UIAlert, but now it is saying the MFMailViewController is not in the hierarchy.

Comment: I'm still not understanding why when I put the entry point of the app on the Tab Bar Controller everything works. But when I put the UIView as the entry point is does not? I have uploaded some pictures to help what i am trying to say.

Comment: try to set parent of an instance MFMailViewController as Main View Controller. You inited an instance of MFMailViewController, but didnt set its parent view controller (instance.parent - is parent controller on instance. It is different from parent view)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You say that over and over (for no reason). You (`self`) are a presented view controller, so you are now dismissing *yourself*. Thus, when you say `self.present`, you are no longer in the view hierarchy.

Comment: That is there to close the keyboard when you hit the button. I have uploaded some picture to help understand my question, why when I put the entry point of the app on the Tab Bar Controller everything works. But when I put the UIView as the entry point is does not?